# Which design pattern to be used?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am facing a basic class design related problem which I am sure is common but I don't have a convincing answer to it. So here goes my problem. Let me put the code snippet first

```
public interface Value {
    void setValue(Object value);
    Object getValue();
}

public interface SimpleValue extends Value {
    void validate();
}

public interface CompoundValue extends Value{
    void setValueAt(int position, Value value);
    Value getValueAt(int position);
    void addValue(Value value);
    List<Value> getValues();
}

public class IntValue implements SimpleValue {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void validate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

public class ComplexValue implements CompoundValue {
    private List<Value>  values;
    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        //Not useful
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        //not useful
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(int position, Value value) {
        values.set(position, value);
    }
    @Override
    public Value getValueAt(int position) {
        return values.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Value> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
    @Override
    public void addValue(Value value) {
        values.add(value);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Value simpleValue = new IntValue();
        Value simpleValue2 = new IntValue();
        ComplexValue complexValue = new ComplexValue();
        Value simpleValue3 = new IntValue();
        complexValue.addValue(simpleValue3);
        ComplexValue complexValue2 = new ComplexValue();
        complexValue2.addValue(simpleValue);
        complexValue2.addValue(simpleValue2);
        complexValue2.addValue(complexValue);
        Value value = complexValue2.getValueAt(2);
        if (value instanceof ComplexValue) {
            ComplexValue compValue = (ComplexValue) value;
            Value finalValue = complexValue.getValueAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

So as you see I have an Interface "Value" which has two variations, one which contains actual values like "IntValue" and other which can hold multiple values. These values can be a simpleValue or a CompoundValue objects

My problem is to work on a ComplexValue Object, I always have to check for its actual class and type cast accordingly to get their functionalities which from design perspective doesn't look to be a decent API design.

I would really appreciate if any one could guide me with suitable design guidelines for this problem or any design pattern to be used here.

Thanks.

Comment: Would it help you if I told you a SimpleValue is a ComplexValue of size 1?

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a bite-sized answer but in general the solution to this type of thing is to use polymorphism.

You have these two distinct types of Value and you have code logic that performs something different depending on the type. Right now you're doing this "on the outside" by decision-making:

```
if(theValue instanceof CompoundValue) {
    // perform CompoundValue action
} else if(theValue instanceof SimpleValue) {
    // perform SimpleValue action
}
```

But `theValue` already knows what kind of Value it is. And so usually the way to handle this is by including this action in the interface, for example:

```
interface PolyValue extends Value {
    public void perform();
}
```

Now you have CompoundValue:

```
class CompoundValue implements PolyValue {
    @Override
    public void perform() {
        // perform CompoundValue action
    }
    ...
}
```

And SimpleValue:

```
class SimpleValue implements PolyValue {
    @Override
    public void perform() {
        // perform SimpleValue action
    }
    ...
}
```

There are many design patterns dealing with this type of situation.

- [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)
- [Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)
- [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

To name a few. Those three are variations on the same idea and the point is just to get away from decision logic.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to provide a generic or shared method in your base value interface and polymorphicly handle calls to the generic method in a specific manner for each of your concrete classes.  If that can not be done then you must perform casts at usage time.  Generics will not help you here.

However, I might suggest a different approach.  Why not simply special case SimpleValue to be a CompoundValue where the size is 1?  Then you only need one value interface and you can have a concrete ComplexValue class implementing Value, and a SimpleValue class extending ComplexValue with the methods filled in so that the size is always 1.

Answer (score 0):

Why are get/setValue methods not "useful" in ComplexValue? Make them useful.
I dont know what your goal is but from the way it seems, you could do this

`public Object getValue() {
        return getValueAt(0);
}`

Then you can remove type casting and simply call *Value.getValue()*